# Support/Alternative of Nashorn with Spring Native

Tags: java, spring, nashorn, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

In my company we use Nashorn in Java 11 and spring-boot which is working fine, but we recently decided to use spring-native with docker. We ended up to make the image build, but at startup, the project crash because the Nashorn is not supported ([And will probably be never supported by graalVM](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/src/com.oracle.svm.core/src/com/oracle/svm/core/jdk/Target_jdk_nashorn_api_scripting_NashornScriptEngineFactory.java#L36)).

[Here is the error I get when tring to run the native image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNOOq.jpg)
[image]

We can't migrate easily from Nashorn to GraalVM.js and the deadline are short, so it's not a solution for us.

I'm asking here if you already had the issue, and how you overcame it.
I already tried to change the ScriptEngine from 'nashorn' to 'js' (which is available in my project), but it also failed at run time. We basically need for an engine which don't use 'invokedynamic' to compute js code.

An other solution would be : Export the Nashorn part as an external microservice.
But we prefere avoid using this solution, since the current implementation is working and it would add some security issue to considere to secure the communication. We will considere it only if we run out of solution ^^'

Here is the problematic code :

Engine.java

```
public class Engine {
    public Engine() { 
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>...</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-object-mappers-gson</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Disable maven resources filtering for bin library files and p12 certificates  -->
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>p12</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>dylib</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>dll</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
<!--                 Build an executable JAR-->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.test.testtest.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.testtest.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dnashorn.args=--language=es6</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <env>local</env>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Is really GraalJS and its nashorn compatibility mode not good enough for you? See https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/ScriptEngine.md

Comment: @Steves Well, I can't really say why it's complicated, our senior backend java said it, and (again!), due to the deadlines, i did't tried it myself. As far as i know, we implmented a custom librairie by using nashorn, and when our senior tried to migrate from nashorn to graal, it broke everything :/. I wasn't the one who tried to migrate, so don't have more information on this. I will still give it a try if i can free up a morning, but i don't have big hope on this. That's why I was asking some help for another solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

Part 1.
Migration from Nashorn to GraalVM.js is standard topic and covered in documentation
https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/NashornMigrationGuide/

And most likely there will not be alternative (at least developed by Oracle)

Part 2. Spring Native (still experimental) is ongoing effort to build Spring application using `native-image` compiler from GraalVM to produce native-image. This project focuses on Spring project and js support will be out of scope, you would need again follow Oracle work.

During this `native-image` build, the engine like GraalVM.js (that is graalVM component) must be included into resulted app, and it may be non trivial.

And life advice: if you really under deadline, consider going with older technologies if you want to guarantee delivery. And use JDK before JDK15 where Nashorn is still present.